# Angular isn't detecting changes in certain project files

Tags: angular, npm

[image: src files]

So, for some reason when I save changes to auth.gaurd.ts, create-order.service.ts, and order.model.ts the changes don't get registered to my application (the other files work just fine).

When I save the files the process that is running with the command ng s -o doesn't reload, when I build my project and push it to the server the changes don't register (and still use an older version of the code I wrote), and when I generate a new service it doesn't work and has the same problems as the first two issues.

I don't really know where to go with this issue, would LOVE to provide any additional information that you would need to look into this issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: What does M and U stand for in the screenshot ? is it a git plugin ?

Comment: Modified and untracked, I guess.

Comment: Does it persist after you close and open VSCode (or whatever editor you're using) again?

Comment: it would seem so, I built the project in the cmd instead of VS code and the problem persists. @Jojofoulk

Comment: I believe that is git @jpavel

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out I was not giving enough information in the question. I should have taken a screen shot of my entire directory (or an snipit of the import code). I have the same named service file in a different folder in the same workspace, and when I auto-imported the service it grabbed a file in a different folder, making the service file I was working on obsolete.